# If $|z^2 + 2019| < 2019$ prove that $|z + \sqrt{2019}| > 31$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I got this from today's test.

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$.
If $|z^2 + 2019| < 2019$ prove that  $|z + \sqrt{2019}| > 31$

I tried triangle inequality, but doesn't work. I also tried using contradiction, that is $|z + \sqrt{2019}| \leq 31$ then letting $z = x + iy$ but then turn to a mess. So far I've got $$(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 4038(x^2 - y^2) < 0$$ from the assumption.

Any hint?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is the question? Or the question hasn’t been misprinted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution follows from the following lemma.

**Lemma.** For $z\in\mathbb C$, we have that
$$|z^2+1|<1\qquad\text{implies}\qquad |z+1|>\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}.$$

The solution follows easily once we have the lemma, since we may introduce a positive real $r>0$ and replace $z$ with $z/r$ to deduce that
$$
|z^2+r^2|<r^2\qquad\text{implies}\qquad |z+r|>\frac{r}{\sqrt 2}.
$$
Taking $r=\sqrt{2019}$ and noting that $\sqrt{2019/2}>31$ yields the solution.

Now for the proof of the lemma, observe that
$$
|z^2+1|^2=(|z|^2-1)^2+(z+\bar{z})^2\geq \frac{(|z|^2+z+\bar{z}-1)^2}{2}=\frac{(|z+1|^2-2)^2}{2},
$$
and thus $|z^2+1|<1$ implies that $|z+1|^2>2-\sqrt{2}$, which is a slightly stronger bound than in the lemma (since $2-\sqrt{2}>1/2$).

**Side note.** Putting the tight bound through, we see that the best constant in place of $31$ is 
$$
\sqrt{2019}\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}\approx 34.39
$$
To see that this truly the best constant, it is necessary to consider the equality case in the inequality we used during the proof of the lemma. In fact, we can tighten the inequality to an *identity*
$$
2|z^2+1|^2=\bigl(|z+1|^2-2\bigr)^2+\bigl(|z-1|^2-2\bigr)^2,
$$
which illuminates what is going on.

Comment: The Lemma is wellknown, atleast by me. I thought it was the same as this, but kinda dont remember it at the test

Comment: Reference for the lemma? I am struggling to solve this problem, I didn’t knew such things exists.

Comment: [+1] I had been looking for such a lemma. As I didn't find an algebraic proof, I turned to a geometrical reasoning, helping in particular to understand why $31$ has been chosen...

Comment: @AjayMishra I have included a proof of the lemma

Comment: Beautiful solution (+1). This Desmos figure shows that $34.39$ is the best constant. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/daobyrqdve

Comment: @CY Aries Pretty lemniscate of Bernoulli !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometrical proof.

Let us prove the (equivalent) contraposal assertion :

$$|z + \sqrt{2019}| \leq 31 \ \  \implies \ \ |z^2 + 2019| \geq 2019\tag{1}$$

Otherwise said, in terms of disks $D((a;b),R)$ where $(a,b)$ is the center and $R$ the radius, let us prove that :

$$z \in \underbrace{D((-\sqrt{2019};0),31)}_{D_1} \ \  \implies \ \ z^2 \notin \underbrace{D((-2019;0),2019)}_{D_2}\tag{2}$$

Consider the figure below featuring disk $D_1$ only, where $OB$ and $OC$ are tangent to $D_1$.

Let $$\alpha:=\arcsin(\dfrac{CB}{OC})=\arcsin(\dfrac{31}{\sqrt{2019}})=0.7614<\dfrac{\pi}{4}.$$

Let us take $z \in D_1$. As $D_1$ is entirely included into the angular sector defined by $AOB$, we have :

$$\pi-\alpha\leq \arg(z)\leq\pi+\alpha.$$

As a consequence,

$$2(\pi-\alpha)\leq \arg(z^2)\leq 2(\pi+\alpha).$$

which amounts to say, mod $2 \pi$  :

$$-2\alpha\leq \arg(z^2)\leq 2\alpha,$$
Therefore, due to the fact that $0< 2 \alpha <\pi/2$, $z^2$ belongs to the half plane $H$ defined by $Re(z)\geq 0$, thus cannot belong to $D_2$ which is included in the complementary set of $H$, reaching the desired RHS of (2).

**Remarks :**

1) $\arcsin(32/\sqrt{2019})= 0.7926 > \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ showing that $31$ has been chosen in a "tight" way.

2) The very particular case $z=0$ which belongs to $H$ and $D_2$ cannot hold because $0$ doesn(t belong to $D_1$.

[image]

Comment: I have rectified an error on the contraposive and a certain number of ill-written facts.

Comment: Remark (1) seems to be suggesting that $31$ cannot be replaced by $32$. However, as you can see from my solution, $31$ is not that tight - it can go as high as $34.39$

Comment: @pre-kidney : No contradiction. I don't say in the absolute that 31 cannot be replaced by 32 ;  I intended to say that if  31 was replaced by 32; we couldn't demonstrate things as we did. Said, otherwise, this limitation is linked to my type of proof which is somewhat more "sharp-edges" than yours.

Comment: Jean Marie, note that the optimal value obtained by your method is $\sqrt{2019/2}\approx 31.77$ (seen by increasing your $\alpha$ to $\pi/4$). It is interesting to note that this coincides precisely with the bound I state in my lemma. In fact, your geometric method has a neat algebraic interpretation, as you are introducing an intermediate (weaker) inequality $z^2+\bar{z}^2\geq 0\implies |z^2+2019|\geq 2019$ corresponding to bounding the circle you call $D_2$ with a half-plane.

Comment: Very interesting remarks indeed. Once more, "bouncing" way  and back between geometric and algebraic interpretations  provides deep insights.